# How to Simplify/Factorise symbolic non-commutative expressions?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, algebraic-manipulation

It always strikes me as odd, that Mathematica seems to have a hard time with non-communative multiplications.

I can use the horrible TensorExpand (or more performant Distribute) to get

```
In: a.(b.c+c.b) // TensorExpand  
Out: a.b.c+a.c.b
```

How can I do the reverse?

```
In: a.b.c+a.c.b // TensorFactorise
Out: a.(b.c+c.b)
```

Comment: try the package http://math.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/
+ ExpandNoncommutativeMultiply